# Does PlayStation 2 slimline have USB 2.0 ports?

Tags: hardware, ps2

I know the classic (fat) PlayStation 2 has two USB 1.1 ports.

Has Sony upgraded slimlines' USB ports (in particular `SCPH-90004`) to 2.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_2_models#Slimline_case_designs) has a page indicating that the Slimline had two USB 1.1 ports, like all other models of the PS2.

An additional Wikipedia source about the technical specifications for the PS2 can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_2_technical_specifications), which also states they are USB 1.1:

> USB 1.1 ports with an OHCI-compatible controller

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the PS2 slimeline has USB 2.0 port which can be used for different purposes such as playing a game from a USB drive, listening to audio from a game, communication in an online game and so on

Comment: do you have code to check? performance are the same as on fat as of now, so